# Woocommerce Product allready in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code to show when the product is already in the cart I need it to show the quantity of the product also.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'wcpt_modify_add_to_cart_text', 9999, 2 );

function wcpt_modify_add_to_cart_text( $text, $product ) {
    
    // if cart is empty return 'Add to Quote'
    if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return 'Add to Quote';

    // otherwise loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
        
        // if cart contains current product ID return its quantity
        if ( $product->get_id() == $product_id ) {
            return $qty . ' - Already Added';
        }
    }

    // if the cart is not empty but the product is not in the cart...
    return 'Add to Quote';
}
```

**UPDATED CODE ABOVE UPDATED WITH HOOKS ASWELL**
The Code Above works wonders thanks to @businessbloomer the only problem now is that I have to refresh the page to see anything

Comment: Your update makes it a little clearer. But: where do you call this function from? via a shortcode? from a template file? through a particular hook? and why are you using `did_action`?

Comment: @7uc1f3r, I have edited my question, and please see the explenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is a bit messy, this revised version should work. I added some inline comments to explain each new section:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'wcpt_modify_add_to_cart_text', 9999, 2 );

function wcpt_modify_add_to_cart_text( $text, $product ) {
    
    // if cart is empty return 'Add to Quote'
    if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return 'Add to Quote';

    // otherwise loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
        
        // if cart contains current product ID return its quantity
        if ( $product->get_id() == $product_id ) {
            return $qty . ' - Already Added';
        }
    }

    // if cart is not empty but product is not in the cart...
    return 'Add to Quote';
}
```

Screenshot:[image: shop page after customization]

Comment: Wow thanks for replying to my post. I have been using your tutorials a lot over the past few months. thanks for them. The code above does not bring up the desired results. even when I add it to the cart the button stays add to quote

Comment: There you go, fixed a couple of bugs. Edited version is tested and works. Adding a screenshot shortly

Comment: have tried this code on a different woo-commerce product table, and it does not work, the code just makes the page load the whole time, any advice

Comment: thanks for the code it worked, I changed add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'wcpt_modify_add_to_cart_text', 9999, 2 ); to add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'wcpt_modify_add_to_cart_text', 9999, 2 ); only problem now is I need to refresh the page for it to change any ideas